# Is Gamecenter sandbox testing possible after app submitted to app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I have submitted the app which has game center in that. Now I want to know that is it possible to do the sandbox testing once it is on app store.

I need to test the app for multiplayer. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a debug build (or any unapproved build, I expect), it will connect to the sandbox rather than to the production Game Center.   If this is for a future version you should probably add a version in iTunes Connect and bump your version numbers, as you will need to do this to ship the update.